# How to find CMVP certificate of the boringssl used in a dev.boringcrypto binary

Tags: go, boringssl

I am deciding to use https://go-boringcrypto.storage.googleapis.com/go1.14.15b4.linux-amd64.tar.gz.

I want to know which exact NIST CMVP certificate number will be applicable for the BoringCrypto module this version has?

From quick search on NIST I can find [these](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search?SearchMode=Basic&Vendor=google&ModuleName=boring&CertificateStatus=Active&ValidationYear=0) certs -

a) [3753](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/3753)
b) [3678](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/3678)
c) [3318](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/3318)
d) [2964](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/2964)

Is there a way to find this? This will be helpful if later we decide to upgrade and use some other version.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
Answer is option (a) - 3753.

Here is the process to find the CMVP for your go+boringcrypto binary -

1. Download the binary that you want to use using this link - https://go-boringcrypto.storage.googleapis.com/go1.14.15b4.linux-amd64.tar.gz. (Note: in my project I am using 1.14.15b4, this could be different number in your case)
2. Unzip it and find file on this path -  go/src/crypto/internal/boring/build/build.sh
   look for these lines -

```
# Following http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp2964.pdf page 18.
if [ ! -e $chroot/boringssl-24e5886c0edfc409c8083d10f9f1120111efd6f5.tar.xz ]; then
    wget -O $chroot/boringssl-24e5886c0edfc409c8083d10f9f1120111efd6f5.tar.xz https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-boringssl-docs/fips/boringssl-24e5886c0edfc409c8083d10f9f1120111efd6f5.tar.xz
```

3. Link for nist cert is - http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp2964.pdf and version of boringssl is - **24e5886c0edfc409c8083d10f9f1120111efd6f5** , which is matching with the version mentioned in the cert.
4. In case these lines are not present in your go/src/crypto/internal/boring/build/build.sh file, it will be present in Dockerfile on this path go/src/crypto/internal/boring/build/build.sh.